# Folders in home directory gone missing

Tags: 12.04

Please help, I am working on Ubuntu 12.04, yesterday one of my folder in home directory 'Videos' gone missing, it says-> Could not find "/home/arun/Videos" Please check the spelling and try again. 
Then today another folder this time Music folder. Leaving with same error notice. I have no idea. Searched many forums to find any solution but no use. Please suggest some solution or reason behind this disappearance of folders.

Comment: When do you receive these error messages? Are you sure no one else messes with your system, since the possibility of a virus is very very bleak.

Comment: Did you log in using a different translation than you were previously using?

Comment: @Jobin: No on else access my system. 2 days ago When I tried to open Videos folder from side pane it said couldn't open. After I found the folder gone missing from my Home folder. I tried whether it is hidden but unable to find. Hence I reboot the system, This time the Folder link missing from the side pane itself. The same thing happened to Music folder.
To dobey: Nope, never used any other.
General info:- Recently I downloaded some .flv from a site a saved them in these two folders. Nothing else.

Comment: @Arun, though the possibility cannot be ruled out, you must check if the files that were in those folders have been shifted to some other location. Do a `find filename` or `locate filename` on these files and check if they are there, else, I don't know what's happening.

Comment: @Jobin: I able to find out where the files are. Few days ago I installed DC++ file sharing client. I found the missing folders both Videos and Music are in .dc++/FileLists folder. Both the file names changed to other names (as some usernames in dc++) I am puzzled how did this happened since, I didn't selected for Sharing option. Have no idea how it grabbed these folders from Home directory to .dc++ (it is also in the Home dir) and accessed by other users. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a matter of language. Folders like `~/Documents/`, `~/Downloads/`, `~/Desktop/`, `~/Music/`, `~/Pictures/` and `~/Videos/` get their names translated into the system language. For example, if your system language is set to French, the folder will be called  `~/Documents/`, `~/Téléchargements/`, `~/Bureau/`, `~/Musique/`, `~/Images/` and `~/Vidéos/`. So you can check if these folders get their translated names into your system language.

**Another idea :**

Unlike Windows, Linux is case sensitive with files and folder names. So if your username is "***A**run*" and not "***a**run*", the `/home/arun/Videos` folder will not exist because of Linux case sensitivity (unlike the `/home/Arun/Videos` folder).

Comment: Dear air-dex, I am well aware about case sensitivity in linux. My system language is English only.

Comment: Guys, I able to find out where the files are. Few days ago I installed DC++ file sharing client. I found the missing folders both Videos and Music are in .dc++/FileLists folder. both file name changed to other names (as some usernames in dc++) I am puzzled how did this happened since, I didn't selected for Sharing option. Have no idea how it grabbed these folders from Home directory to .dc++ (it is also in the Home dir) and accessed by other users.